# Unable to Trigger Kubeless Function With Kubeless Kafka Trigger

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubeless

I'm attempting to trigger a Kubeless function (written as a Java method) and it doesn't seem to be working. I've tried everything I can think to try, but I've run out of ideas. Below is the Java method (it's basically an echo service, for now).

```
package io.kubeless;

import io.kubeless.Context;
import io.kubeless.Event;

public class MyHandler {
    public String handle(Event event, Context context) {
        return event.Data;
    }
}
```

The method was deployed using the following:

```
$ kubeless function deploy my-handler --runtime java1.8 --handler MyHandler.handle --from-file src/main/java/io/kubeless/MyHandler.java
```

I have verified it works by running the following:

```
$ kubeless function call my-handler --data "It works"
$ kubectl logs my-handler-6f67d567c5-r8cdb
    0 [pool-1-thread-38] INFO io.kubeless.Handler  - Response: It works
```

I then [created a Kafka trigger](https://kubeless.io/docs/pubsub-functions/) and published a message to it using the following.

```
$ kubeless trigger kafka create test --function-selector created-by=kubeless,function=my-handler --trigger-topic test-topic
$ kubeless topic publish --topic test-topic --data "Hello from Kafka"
$ kubectl logs my-handler-6f67d567c5-r8cdb
    0 [pool-1-thread-38] INFO io.kubeless.Handler  - Response: It works
```

As you can see, the only log entry is the one from the initial call that wasn't triggered by a Kafka pub/sub. I have verified the trigger exists:

```
$ kubeless trigger kafka ls
NAME    NAMESPACE   TOPIC       FUNCTION SELECTOR
test    default     test-topic  function=my-handler
```

As far as I can tell, Kafka seems to be running (I've also checked the Kafka logs, to no avail):

```
$ kubectl get pods --namespace=kubeless
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kafka-0                                       1/1     Running   0          170m
kafka-trigger-controller-f6f7c699f-m6mcd      1/1     Running   0          170m
kubeless-controller-manager-59d484f4d-9wlhq   3/3     Running   10         4d22h
zoo-0                                         1/1     Running   0          170m
```

Why is publishing not triggering the function? Any suggestions are appreciated and I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I nerded out on this and there's an issue with the Kubeless [kafka-trigger](https://github.com/kubeless/kafka-trigger). Essentially, I'm getting this log when the message is picked up by the controller and tries to trigger the function:

```sh
time="2020-07-14T22:00:15Z" level=error msg="Unable to elaborate request: Unable to find the service for function my-handler"
```

This means that the controller cannot find the `my-handler` service to trigger the function. If you see the [code](https://github.com/kubeless/kafka-trigger/blob/68a3798a36e725fb15c2dac4d4dc56274d075c3b/pkg/utils/event_sender.go#L43), you see that it's a call to the K8s API server. So, my guess is that there's an API version mismatch on the newer K8s versions. My server is `v1.18.2`. I've created [this issue](https://github.com/kubeless/kafka-trigger/issues/30) to track.

Comment: I wanted to thank you for this yesterday, but I had been up since 3:00 AM and couldn't articulate anything to save my life. At any rate, my server is v1.18.3, so probably not much of a difference between us there. There has since been a reply to the issue you created, indicating Kubeless is not compatible with Kubernetes 1.18. I very much appreciate you taking the time to help me out with this. I'm new to both Kubernetes and Kubeless, so I was struggling to find anything more valuable in the log output to help me debug the issue.